# Output recursive array into table

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, format

I've seen lots of questions about creating recursive arrays, but not about outputting or formatting them.

I have a recursive array that returns a directory list of **FOLDERS ONLY**;

Array ( [0] => clients [kevin] => Array ( [subkevin] => Array ( ) ) [tony] => Array ( ) )

**the directory looks like**
clients/
clients/kevin/
clients/kevin/subkevin/
client/tony

I'm having trouble trying to get my head around recursions, in order to turn my array in to a table formatted like below (the below table is then turned into a directory tree using Maxazan's jQuery TreeGrid;
http://maxazan.github.io/jquery-treegrid/examples/example-basic.html

```
<table class="tree">
    <tr class="treegrid-1">
      <td>clients</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="treegrid-2 treegrid-parent-1">
      <td>kevin</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="treegrid-3 treegrid-parent-2">
      <td>subkevin</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="treegrid-4 treegrid-parent-1">
      <td>tony</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

I'm not necessarily asking someone to write the code for me (if someone is bored and has lots of spare time, then by all means feel free) but I need help in understanding how to write recursive functions in order to convert my array into the table structure shown below.

The treegrid class on the TR elements, increment by 1 for each element, the treegrid-parent however should list the treegrid ID of its parent folder.

Can anybody give me some advice/guidance/direction/starting-point on this?

I know a lot of PHP, but have never dealt with recursive arrays and am struggling a little with this.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks for reading.